# How to validate controls of the form before closing the form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, validation

I have written handlers for Validating events of the controls of the form. How can I trigger validation of the all elements on the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ValidateChildren()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159409.aspx) method.

Comment: It already runs automatically before the FormClosing event is raised.  e.Cancel will be true before the event handler is entered.

Comment: @Hans, oh I see, I misunderstood `before` in the question title. I'll remove the code sample. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve that by invoking [`ValidateChildren`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.validatechildren.aspx) on the form.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to handle the [Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) event on the form and in there do a call to the [Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wf8t2at.aspx) method. Based on the return value you would either let the form close or cancel the closing of the form.